# How to get string values from enums in a protobuf grpc definition?

Tags: c#, .net-core, postman, grpc

Apologies if this is a duplicate question, I've searched through previous posts and can't find anything similar, so assume I'm misunderstanding something.

I'm using the latest Grpc.AspNetCore NuGet package (2.53.0) and .net-core 7.0.5.

I've generated a .proto file with an enum definition like this:

```
enum BookStatus {
    IDEA = 0;
    ...
    PUBLISHED = 7;
}
```

and I am using it in messages for requests and responses like this:

```
message BookRequest {
    optional string id = 1;
    ...
    optional BookStatus bookStatus = 4;
    ...
}
```

```
message BookResponse {
    string id = 1;
    ...
    optional BookStatus bookStatus = 7;
}
```

When importing the .proto file into Postman, the JSON payload is suggested to be:
`"bookStatus": "IDEA",` and it type-hints all the other options, `"PUBLISHED"` etc...

But in the generated cs class, it always defaults the BookStatus property to 0.

My classes are extending the default, generated base partial class and all other properties are working as expected through postman.

I've tried updating the definition in the proto file to use strings, but the enum requires integer values. I've tried setting integer values in the postman payload but that still defaults to 0.

I'm expecting at the very least for postman to type-hint the values the same as the c# code can deserialize.

Comment: "I'm expecting at the very least for postman to type-hint the values the same as the c# code can deserialize." - the C# code should be able to deserialize either integers or strings. That's the default for the JsonParser that does this. What exactly do you mean by "in the generated cs class, it always defaults the BookStatus property to 0"? That will always be the *default* value for an enum...

Comment: @JonSkeet I have the generated CrudGrpc.cs file (my file is called crud.proto) that I am assuming is generated by Grpc - it seems to get regenerated when I build the project each time I make changes to the .proto file. But if I put a JSON value of `"bookStatus": "PUBLISHED"` in my message in postman, and send it, when I print the value in my Service which receives the BookRequest, with this code:
`Console.WriteLine(b.BookStatus);`
the console prints:
`Idea`

Comment: Right - please clarify that in the question. I'd *expect* that to work, but it would be good to see the complete HTTP request, *ideally* along with a minimal complete code example to let us reproduce it. (I'm far more familiar with gRPC in the context of Google servers rather than ASP.NET Core, but if you can provide a [mcve] I'm happy to look into it.)

Comment: It seems the issue might be related to being sent in a repeatable property. I have a Series, which has a repeatable list of Books. If I create a Book as an individual, setting the bookStatus works as expected. But when it is in the array of Books in a Series, it defaults the value to the first item in the enum.

Comment: Again, a [mcve] would make this easier to look into. (As an aside, it's "the enum value with a numeric value of 0" that is the default, not just "the first declared one" - they're the same in your case, but don't always have to be.)

Comment: Yea appreciate it being the 0. I'm working on a minimal example and will get something up. It's looking like an issue with the interpretation of gRPC within the c# library, and will get something together to see if it can be reliably reproduced

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for your response to this. It looks like the issue was simply that I wasn't allowing the c# generated code to be up to date. From further investigation, and trying a few things out, it appears that things get updated in a strange order, so building the project generates a new c# base class which you extend from, but it doesn't seem to be loaded in for the rest of the code to use, you have to rebuild the project again afterwards. I would imagine I have something back to front in my build process, build user code -> then build protobuf helper class.